# When using SQL API's for .NET (C#), what should I out as the file's extension?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm using the binaries from Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

The code is:

```
bkup.Devices.AddDevice(dbName, DeviceType.File);

bkup.CompressionOption = BackupCompressionOptions.On;
```

The extensions for the compressed .bak files are not there... is it .rar, .zip, etc, etc?

My program successfully backups up the dbs, but people are annoyed that there are no file extensions. The documentation for this API, says nothing about an extension when using `BackupCompressions.On`

Does anyone know?  (sources appreciated)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you both for your help. I'll use .bak as the extension because it would be nice for users to know what type of file they're downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use '.bak' exstension for compressed backups. Maybe I'm wrong, but I cannot see why the extesion should be changed if backup is compressed.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server compresses data as it performs the backup.  It does not first create a backup file and the compresses it using zip or rar, so you cannot use a tool such as zip or rar to un-compress the backup file.  Compressed backup files only make sense to SQL Server itself.